# How to configure onclick function if the element is inside a loop?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to toggle display element `<div>` on clicking the button 'Reply'.

```
{% for row in check %}
        <li>
          <hr>
          <p><font color="green">{{row.username}}</font> :
          {{row.comment}}</p>
            <button onclick="myFunction()">Reply</button>  
            <div id="id" style="display:none">
                <form action="http://localhost/adarsh-abraham/index.php/post/comment/{{row.id}}" method="POST">
                    <textarea rows="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Add your comment here" name="comment" required></textarea>
                    <div>
                        Calculate : <img src="http://localhost/adarsh-abraham/captcha.jpg" />
                        <input name="captcha" type="text" required><br>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="cmid" value={{row.cmid}}>
                    <input type="submit" value="submit">
                </form>
            </div>
          {% if not row['children']|default([]) is empty %}
            {{ macro.tree(row['children']) }}
          {% endif %}
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
```

I tried to achieve this by a function myFunction().

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("id");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

But only the text box of first reply button is displaying no matter which reply button I click.

Comment: You would have to provide a different id each loop, and pass that id through into your function, and utilise it there.

Comment: You're giving many elements the id of `id` where these should all be unique. getElementById will only return the first of these.

Comment: @Kobe Since I am using recursive function to display elements in html, even if I initialise an id at the beginning and increment it, it gets re-initialised everytime recursion occurs.

Comment: @Gavin I am new to javascript. I cannot find a way to give different id on different function call. Can you suggest one?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make any changes to your loop you can instead change how your function and the div you want to hide are identified.

Try setting a class on the div, and passing 'this' into the function. Below the function is getting the parent of the div, then finding the 'hide-me' classes inside it and hiding them.

```js
function myFunction(elem) {
  let button = elem;
  let parent = button.parentNode;
  let elements = parent.getElementsByClassName('hide-me');
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    const element = elements[i];
    element.style.display = (element.style.display != 'block' ? 'block' : 'none')
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="myFunction(this)">Reply</button>
  <div class="hide-me" style="display:none">foobar</div>
</div>

<div>
  <button onclick="myFunction(this)">Reply</button>
  <div class="hide-me" style="display:none">foobar</div>
</div>

<div>
  <button onclick="myFunction(this)">Reply</button>
  <div class="hide-me" style="display:none">foobar</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

first pass argument like following

```
<button onclick="myFunction({{row.id}})">Reply</button>
```

then give id to form as following

```
<div id="{{row.id}}" style="display:none">
```

then just copy paste following function

```
function myFunction(id) {
    let x = $("#".id);
    if (x.css('display') === "none") {
        x.css('display', 'block');
    } else {
        x.css('display', 'none');
    }
}
```